# Form data displays null object

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have made a simple form and want to post the data using the jQuery function `new FormData()`. To me every thing seems to be good but when I am displaying the variable `data` in `console.log`, then I get `FormData { append=append()}` as output.

My code is:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="edit_user" id="edit_user">
   <input type="text" name="Fname" >
   <input type="file" name="image">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#edit_user').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formdata = new FormData(this);
            console.log(formdata);
       });
```

Comment: `FormData()` is not a `jQuery API method/function`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Question re-tagged properly.

Comment: If you're still after `jQuery`, this might help you: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: friends i need to upload a image file so how can that be possible with serialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code (included below) works fine. This is how `FormData` is supposed to work. The data can be posted using XHR or `$.ajax` (see [this question for tying it to jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)), but it is not serialised into a string for you. It is only converted into the appropriate format when the XHR request is made.

There is no way to see the data in a `FormData` object in the console without making the XHR request.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit_user').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //enter code here
    var formdata = new FormData(this);

    console.log(formdata);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="edit_user" id="edit_user">
  <input type="text" name="Fname">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks dude you saved me... i was debugging this for a2 hours

Comment: @lonesomeday Is there any way to console formdata values in http request?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data by using get function of FormData like this:

```
console.log(formdata.get('Fname'));
```